# Определение координат мыши в canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Как определить значения `x`, `y` при нажатии мыши на `<canvas>`? И чтобы эти значения были у переменой сразу.

```js
var example = document.getElementById("example"),
        ctx = example.getContext('2d');
example.width = 300; //высота
example.height = 300; //ширина
for (x = 0; x < 300; x += 100) { //поле крестиков ноликов
    for (y = 0; y < 300; y += 100) {
        ctx.strokeRect(x, y, 100, 100);
    }
}
pic = new Image();
pic.src = "нолик.png";
//pic.onload = function() {
    //example.onmouseup = ctx.drawImage(pic, 101, 1);
//}
//нужна функция
```

```html
<canvas id='example'>Обновите браузер</canvas>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
example.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
    var x = e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft,
        y = e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop;
    ⁄⁄.......
});
```

Comment: я просто добавил ваш код и канвас просто пропал.Что делать?

Comment: Посмотрите в консоли разработчика, видимо где-то ошибка, блокирующая выполнение скрипта.

Comment: @AleksanderK. предполагаю что Вам будет интересен мой ответ

Answer (score 3):

**Решением из принятого ответа следует пользоваться с осторожностью**, если масштаб элемента (css `zoom` не работает в последних firefox) не `100%`, то положение мыши относительно логических пикселей в `canvas` сбивается, точнее так же масштабируется, как и элемент:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('canvas')].forEach(canvas => {
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) { 
      var x = e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft,
          y = e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop; 
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,100,100);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(x,y,5,0,Math.PI*2,true);
      ctx.stroke();
  });
});
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas width=100 height=100></canvas>
<canvas width=100 height=100 style="zoom:150%"></canvas>
```

Бороться с этим можно вот так:

```
let z = window.getComputedStyle(canvas).zoom;     
var x = e.pageX/z - e.target.offsetLeft,
    y = e.pageY/z - e.target.offsetTop;
```

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('canvas')].forEach(canvas => {
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
          let z = window.getComputedStyle(canvas).zoom || 1;     
          var x = e.pageX/z - e.target.offsetLeft,
              y = e.pageY/z - e.target.offsetTop;
          ctx.clearRect(0,0,100,100);
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(x,y,5,0,Math.PI*2,true);
          ctx.stroke(); 
      });
});
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
<canvas width=100 height=100></canvas>
<canvas width=100 height=100 style="zoom:150%"></canvas>
```